# React formik and select array to string Convert onSubmit

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, formik, react-select

React formik and react select package are I am using . I created on form that contains user can create new and Edit also working in same form. I have an one multi select field that field values are in array I want to change to string send to server on onSubmit. And also on update I want to get the string value convert array set to select field. I try it but cant found solution .please give me any ideas It helpful for me
codeSandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselect-formik-3eqxp?file=/src/RegisterForm.js
Thanks for help

Comment: Is there any answers below suit your need? if no, can you elaborate what result you expect to get?

Comment: yes Issue was fixed by the below answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the field value change the array to string on before submit. we want bind the change string value on field. It will be working fine for me.

Code Sandbox link :https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselect-formik-3eqxp?file=/src/RegisterForm.js:657-844

```
 function create(fields) {
    console.log(fields);
    const jobs = [];
    fields.job.map((ele) => jobs.push(ele.value));
    fields.job = jobs.toString();
    console.log(fields);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this what you are looking for, but i did

```
     function create(fields) {
    fields.job = JSON.stringify(fields.job)
    console.log(fields);
  }
```

or

```
  function create(fields) {
    const jobs = [];
    fields.job= fields.job.map((ele) => jobs.push(ele.value));
    console.log(fields);
  }
```

instead of

```
  function create(fields) {
    console.log(fields);
    const jobs = [];
    fields.job.map((ele) => jobs.push(ele.value));
    const job = ("text => ", jobs.toString());
    console.log(job);
    console.log(fields);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the value from the array where the result should be

`{name: "111", fatherName: "222", job: ["enginner", "painter"] }`

```js
function create(fields) { 
    const amendedFields = {
      ...fields,
      job: fields.job.map((ele) => ele.value) // extract value from object,  ["enginner", "painter"]
    }; // not mutating the current fields object, copy it and mutate the new one.
    console.log("old", fields);
    console.log("new", amendedFields);
}
```